# How do you find appropriate missions as a new player?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I'm a brand new player and I'm having some difficulty finding missions to run. The station my character is created at doesn't have any available that I can take. There are some other stations in the system (if I recall, I'm in a binary system), but

1. They're quite far even in supercruise
2. Travelling takes fuel which costs money and I have very little of it
3. There's no guarantee a station even has a mission I qualify for, let alone willing to take.

So, how do I find appropriate missions as a brand new player? What types of missions, assuming I can even find any available, would be appropriate and how can I tell that the mission is of that type?

Answer (score 3):

Missions are found either while in space (e.g. Distress Calls) or from Bulletin Boards (BB). Since you are new to the game I would advise to stick to BBs for the moment. They display all available missions, whether you meet the requirements to accept them or not. The interface will split missions into "Available" and "Unavailable". If no missions are available to you you can wait until the BB refreshes, typically 10 minutes, and check again.

It may, however, be that no missions show up for you repeatedly. In that case I'd advise to get to a new station. Don't be afraid to visit another station in the same system (costs about 10Cr in fuel) or a nearby system (costs more fuel but is still affordable).
You can always take on some cargo and transport it to a system that is noted to receive this cargo as export from your current system. You will be guaranteed to make a profit, even if not a huge one. They should however cover all your travel costs.

What mission you want to take on is up to you and how you want to play the game. Generally, you can take on trading or errant missions, combat missions against pirates or specific non-pirate targets, or mining. There are a few other types that have been added with the latest patch but all of these fall into two main categories as specified by the rank they require; they either require a combat or merchant rank.

As a last advice, don't be afraid to die or run out of fuel (and self-destruct). You will always be able to reacquire your starting ship at no cost (other than the inconvenience of defaulting back to your start location).